# Why is boost::checked_delete "intentionally complex"?

Tags: c++, boost

So I was looking through some boost source code and came across this:

(from `<boost/checked_delete.hpp>`)

```
template<class T> inline void checked_delete(T * x)
{
    // intentionally complex - simplification causes regressions
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
    (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
    delete x;
}
```

Anyone happen to know why it is implemented in this way? Wouldn't sizeof(T) (for example) already be enough?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Someone asked the same question earlier](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-checked-delete-hpp-td2661980.html). This post written by Peter Dimov ([one of the writers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/checked_delete.hpp) of `boost/checked_delete.hpp`) pretty much speaks for itself:

> > - What's the result of applying sizeof to an incomplete type?
>
> A compile-time error, unless the compiler chooses to return 0 as a 
>   nonstandard extension.
>
> > - Why is sizeof called twice?
>
> The second sizeof is a workaround for a Metrowerks CodeWarrior bug in
>   which  the first typeof is never instantiated unless used.
>
> > - Why is the result of sizeof cast to void? What exactly does that
> >       line 
> >       do?
>
> Silences a compiler warning.

Comment: Doh! Beat my psychic powers by a minute! Still it's nice to know my guesswork was quite accurate :-)

Comment: @Praetorian: I had the same suspicion about the `sizeof(T)? 1: -1` expression, but I wanted to get it straight from (one of the) authors themselves. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is just a guess; but there may be compilers out there that just emit a warning when you write `sizeof(incomplete_type)` and return `0`. So you're making sure the array declaration fails in that case by trying to declare an array of size -1.